# how to get result from wscript.execute() I need piping

Tags: pipe, wsh

I want to get result from an executing command by the help of wscript say :

```
wscript.execute("dir c:\")
```

I need to know how can I access to the results of this or in other words I want to know how can I pipe the result into my script?

regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a shell object:

```
var shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
```

Then there are two methods to choose from. The easy way uses the Shell Run function and sends the command output to a file, which you subsequently read:

```
var errorCode = shell.Run("cmd /c dir c:\\ > tmp.txt", 1, true); 
    // (1 -> Display window, true -> wait for command to finish)
```

Alternatively, it is also possible to capture the command output directly using the Shell Exec function:

```
var cmdRun = shell.Exec("cmd /c dir c:\\");
while (cmdRun.Status == 0) // wait for the command to finish
{
  WScript.Sleep(100);
}
```

Exec returns an object representing the process, in this case we access the standard output as a TextStream object.

```
var output = cmdRun.StdOut.ReadAll();
```

You might expect that you'd be able to interact with the new process using the returned object and its standard I/O pipes, but that doesn't seem to work in my experience. For example, I can't find a way of reading the standard output that doesn't block the script until the command has finished executing.